# What is the point of hashing an API key?

Tags: authentication, hash, api

Within my API backend i have a unique `KeySalt` for every API Key

```
public string Key { get; set; }

public byte[] KeySalt { get; set; }

public string KeyHash { get; set; }
```

When the user creates a new API key, I present the generated Key only once, (and store only the last 4 characters in the Key field) so the user can use it within my windows forms application.

With that been said, my windows forms application, should have besides the `Key` and the `KeySalt` in order to generate the `KeyHash`, so I can validate it against the `KeySalt` on the database.

The last one, doesn't mean that the user should also login first from my windows forms application to get the `KeySalt`?

For this reason, I feel that I have a chicken egg issue and missing something in the whole process. What am I missing here?

Comment: Not a clear question, though, have you ever heard Key Encryption key and Symmetric Key encapsulation Mechanism like the VeraCrypt uses?

Comment: Why are you doing any of this? What are you trying to prevent?

Comment: @MechMK1 Just trying to store the api keys hashed in database